# Hubspot and Google Analytics - Pass session source and medium information

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-analytics, hubspot

I’m trying to pass session source and medium information into HubSpot so that if a form is filled out / some other conversion event happens, I can tell where that specific session started.

From the HubSpot side, this should be a two-field solution — e.g. the session and medium get passed across into fields that update with each new visit. If a form gets filled out, it will copy the session and medium data across to more permanent fields.

The end result of this process will mean that I’ll be able to say “we got 100 people to download our ebook this month. 8 came from email, 70 came from organic search, and 22 came from social media”.

All I can say right now is “we got 100 people to download our ebook. I have no idea where they’re from.”

I would like to know if this would be possible to do using Google Analytics and Hubspot as well as some script.

Upon researching I have found these two scripts that may be relevant to this:

https://github.com/troyfawkes/dgacquisition

and this:

http://sbjs.rocks/#/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`sbjs` works great for this if all your campaigns have proper utm tags.
However, you might have set this up the other way and send a specific event to Google Analytics each time a user fills a specific form. then you can set up a goal for that event and use Acquisition reports to answer your exact question "where my conversions come from?"